# Getting the best 6 subjects including a compulsory subject in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a student grade system, that calculates a student final mark. A student, for example, can do 10 subjects, but only the best 6 are calculated to come up with the student average.

The current code I have calculates all the marks and divides by the number of subjects. For example, if a student has 8 subjects the system will add all the 8 subjects marks and divide by 8.

Yet it has to select the best 6 inclusive of English which is a passing/compulsory subject.

I have a table that stores the student marks

```
INSERT INTO `assesmentxmarks`(`id`, `student_id`, `teacher_id`, `assessement_id`, `subject_id`, `class_id`, `mark`, `added`) VALUES (NULL,stu-23,teacher-34,T1,Ssub3,1A,93,NOW())
```

Above is the table-structure for the table where marks are entered.

```
SELECT ROUND((SUM(mark)/2)/8) as AVG FROM `assesmentxmarks` WHERE student_id='stu-23'
```

This will calculate the average but will take all 8 subjects and divide by 8, when it is supposed to only take the best 6 subjects (the top 6 marks)
In this case, the students had written 2 tests and then the query gets the subject average of the two tests by dividing by 2 and then divides all the subject averages by 8 since the student does 8 subjects.

how can I only calculate taking in only the top 6 marks (inclusive of English, even if it is not in the top 6 categories) and calculate the student average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
select * from assesmentxmarks
where student_id = 'stu-23'
order by (subject_id = 'English') desc, mark desc
limit 6
```

returns the rows that you want.
So find the average of the marks of the those rows:

```
select round(avg(t.mark), 1)  average_mark
from (
  select * from assesmentxmarks
  where student_id = 'stu-23'
  order by (subject_id = 'English') desc, mark desc
  limit 6
) t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qciNUmMsvSKRfWJnxAYQks/2).
Result:

```
| average_mark |
| ------------ |
| 68.3         |
```

Comment: This one is working, except that it does not factor in the the test 2. In the table, there is test 1 and test 2 and that is averaged to get the single average for each subject. For example, History has Test 1 and Test 2 and that is averaged to get the overal average of History.

Comment: This code answers to the question as you posted it. If you have another requirement then post a new question.

Comment: thanks @forpas. you have really helped me. in the event i want to exclude a certain subject from the averae calculation lets say computer how would i go about it

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qciNUmMsvSKRfWJnxAYQks/6